# iOS 13 - FileManager url(forPublishingUbiquitousItemAt:expiration:) not working anymore

Tags: ios, swift, nsfilemanager, beta, ios13

I've developed an iOS app that uses the `url(forPublishingUbiquitousItemAt:expiration:)` method of Apple's `FileManager` class. Starting with the first Beta of iOS 13 this function stopped working and now it throws an error, stating "`This code has been removed. You should switch off of this SPI`". But I can't find anything related to this function neither in the release notes of iOS nor in the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/filemanager/1411577-url) for this function, and it even states there that it would be supported on Mac Catalyst 13.0+.

This also has nothing to do with Xcode 10 and 11, as it occurs when the app is built using either one of those versions.

Does anyone of you know more about that? It would be great to get new information on that.

Thanks,
Fabian.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is fixed in **iOS 13 beta 6**. Updated today and this error magically disappeared!

Had my mind blown when I saw this error message.